# Hiberate query not returning newly added records from same transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

My Entity is like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Item parent;
}
```

I am doing 3 things in a single transaction

1. Persist some items using EntityManager
2. hibernate query "from item where id in newIdList"
3. hibernate query "from item where parent=parentid"

In First step after persisting new items I do `entityManager.flush();` and flush mode here is commit. 
In second step I do given hibernate query. Here I get the proper result but in third step when I do hibernate query it returns me the results. But this result does not contain the newly persisted query.

I think the problem is due to parentId condition. As per requirements I cannot change the condition. Is there any way we can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@JoinColumn does not establish a relationship from Item > Parent.

You need to annotate this relationship with the relevant association mapping, @OneToOne, @ManyToMany, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try 3rd step after commit... This is not direct solution to your problem but just give a try..